# Prevent remapping of default namespace

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an xml document as below. I am trying to remove the element "b" and replace it with "changedB" and all other elements should just get copied over. My issue is, when the "input" element gets copied over it already has the default namespace mapped to an empty prefix. But when my template replaces "b" with "changedB" it remaps the namespace with a prefix. How can I avoid the additional myns:changedB xlmns:myns from appearing only for elementB. It looks odd in the transformed output although its a legal XML document.

XML:

```
<input xmlns="http://mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>elementa</a>
    <b>elementb</b>
</input>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:myns="http://mynamespace.com"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://mynamespace.com">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//b">
        <myns:changedB><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></myns:changedB>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><input xmlns="http://mynamespace.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>elementa</a>
    <myns:changedB xmlns:myns="http://mynamespace.com">elementb</myns:changedB>
</input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the template for `b` to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="//b">
    <xsl:element name="changedB" namespace="http://mynamespace.com">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```